# ARDUINO: Combine all the characters of a serial input

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I'm trying to check if an entered response (input from the serial monitor) matches a certain item in an array.

When the user enters his response trought `digital.read()`, the program checks if it corresponds to, in this case, the first item of an array (CARD_ID[0]).

However, the response is split into 4 different parts, it does the checking for every character of the response. How can I take the entire response and then do the checking for it?

The program works fine if I want to check the response with the items in the array NAME because the items are 1 character long.

```
char CARD_ID[] = {'0000', '0001', '0010', '0011', '0100', '0101', '0110', '0111', '1000', '1001', '1010', '1011', '1100', '1101', '1110', '1111'};
char NAME[16] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q'};
int i = 0;
char reponse;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    reponse = Serial.read();
    if (reponse == CARD_ID[i]){
        Serial.println("Yes");
    }
    else {
        Serial.println("No");
    }
  }
}
```

Serial Monitor output:

When 0000 is entered:

```
No
No
No
No
```

Expected output:

```
Yes
```

Comment: Are you aware that `'0000'` is not a string of 4 characters but one multicharacter constant with an implementation defined value? It has type `int` which is then converted to one `char` value during initialization of `CARD_ID`.

Comment: You should change the title; this is about reading from Serial, and not about digital.read() (which doesn't exist BTW; it's called digitalRead()).

Answer (score 1):

You should string all the `Serial.read()` outputs (single `char`s) together until you get a return (entered by the user), so you know you have the whole response before checking it against the array.

Alternatively, use [`Serial.readStringUntil()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/readstringuntil/) with `'\r'` as the termination character.

Also, `if (reponse == CARD_ID[i])` should be in a loop; `i` never gets increased so it only checks against the array's first element.

Also, you are comparing `response` with `CARD_ID[i]` using `==`, which may not work.

Also, use double quotes for the values in the `CARD_ID[i]` array.